# Проблема в цикле each()

Tags: jquery

Есть следующее:

```
<div class="gTable">
 <td class="forumNameTd"><a class="forum" href="">a</a></td>
 <td class="forumNameTd"><a class="forum" href="">b</a></td>
 <td class="forumNameTd"><a class="forum" href="">c</a></td>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.gTable').each(function() {
  var forum_uname = $(this).find('.forum').text()+'<hr>';
  alert(forum_uname)
 });
</script>
```

По идее, в alert-e должно быть так: "`a<hr>b<hr>c<hr>`", а выдаёт так: "`abc<hr>`". В чём проблема?

Comment: А, прошу прощенья, не правильно вопрос прочитал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [доков](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

То есть в вашем случае `text()` возвращает скомбинированный текст из массива, полученного после `$(this).find('.forum')`. А `$(this).find('.forum')` возвращает массив ссылок `<a class="forum" />`.

Соответственно, в `text()` возвратит `'a'+'b'+'c'` = 'abc'.

Чтобы решить вашу задачу, лучше использовать функцию [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) и проходить не по `.gTable`, а по `.forum`:

```
$('.forum').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()+'<hr>';
}).get().join('');
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hDRY6/).

Comment: Отлично. Но почему теперь не работает так?

 var text = $(this).find('.forum').map(function() {
        return $(this).text()+'<hr>';
 }).get().join('');

  var forum_tmpls = '<div class="gTableTop"><a href="">'+text+'</a></div>';

Comment: Извините, кто мне сможет помочь по jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

[вот здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/vfvtnjd/Rg4gT/)

```
$('.gTable').each(function() {
   $(this).find('.forum').each(
      function(){
          var t = $(this).text();
          t = t+'<hr>';
          $(this).text(t);}
      );

 });
```

Comment: другого способа нет? а то элементов .forum, .theme много и так каждый раз each прописывать..

Comment: @Руслан Дуров, так для чего функции-то придумали? К примеру:

    function appendText(el) {
        return function() {
            return $(this).text() + el;
        };
    }

И далее используйте через map:

    var forum_uname = $(this).find('.forum')
        .map(appendText('<hr>')).toArray().join('');

Comment: Мм. Благодарю. Очень выручил!

Answer (score 1):

```
var forum_uname = '';
$('.gTable .forum').each(function(key, val) {
    forum_uname += $(val).text()+'<hr>';
});
alert(forum_uname);
```